Как правильно создать правило для cron
Требуется автоматически запускать скрипт, использую для этого правило
00 13 * * 1-5 python3 /путь/к/файлу/script.py

Но получаю ошибку
Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/путь/к/файлу/script.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Если просто ввести команду
python3 /путь/к/файлу/script.py

то все отрабатывает

Надо смотреть под каким пользователем запускается крон. И какие права стоят на файл скрипта.  Возможно ситуацию может спасти chmod 755 /путь/к/файлу/script.py Но это не точно.

@VladimirIgnatenko, такую команду запускала, не помогло

При использовании macos необходимо разрешить cron полный доступ к диску
Системные настройки -> Конфиденциальность и безопасность -> Доступ к диску -> нажимаете "+" и выбираете из папки /usr/sbin cron
